# Android onCreate: Thread.sleep() causes content to be drawn in unexpected way

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

Having had a formal introduction to concurrency, I feel rather comfortable with concurrency. As I am new to Android, I set out to write a simple activity that calls itself recursively 10 times in a row and prints the depth in the recursion.

The whole code is contained within the onCreate method:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get recursion count
        Intent wasStartedWith = getIntent();
        final int cnt = wasStartedWith.getIntExtra("count", 0);

        // Update UI
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                tv.setText(cnt + "th recursive call");
            }
        });

        // Sleep 500ms before (possible) recursive call
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Check if non-basecase
        if (cnt != 10)
        {
            // Recursive call
            Intent recursiveIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            recursiveIntent.putExtra("count", cnt + 1);
            startActivity(recursiveIntent);
        }
}
```

Given the mostly sequential nature of the method, I expected the following execution order:

1. Activity called from Launcher
2. runOnUiThread gets called, the runnable object is passed to the UI thread which concurrently updates the textView
3. The main thread (!= UI thread) sleeps for 500ms
4. The main thread, assuming it wasn't interrupted, checks whether it is the 10th recursive call. If not, it creates a new intent, populates an extra and dispatches it.
5. Goto 2

Confusingly, I get very weird behavior upon opening the app:

1. Screen is blank , not even the titlebar is shown
2. After several hundred ms, the screen briefly flashes the expected content for a few ms
3. Goto 1

During this execution, roughly every second recursive call actually gets displayed in step 2 (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10).

**My questions:**

1. Given that the UI thread runs concurrently (i.e. is not affected by the Thread.sleep() of main thread), why isn't the screen drawn right as the activity is started?
2. What should I do to get the expected behavior?

Comment: You're working under a false premise. The UI thread is indeed the main thread for your app. The `Thread.sleep()` is hanging the UI thread, which is why nothing draws immediately.

Comment: Oh wow, I just assumed that the naming of runOnUiThread was to be taken as "to be run on a dedicated UI thread"... Guess not everything is as it seems. Having just checked the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)), I found the line: *"If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately."* Per that line, I would still expect the whole UI updating (and drawing) to take place before the Thread.sleep()?

Comment: UI events and updates are processed through a message queue. Those UI modifications you're making first (indeed, the whole initial layout and draw) are basically only queued up, and when you `sleep()` in `onCreate()`, that hangs the whole thread, including the processing of that message queue, so the UI layout and draw, including your updates, don't happen until the `sleep()` is done. Follow me?